# Where can I find the screenlog.0 file?

Tags: gnu-screen

I have to run some scripts in a screen and I used the `C-a H` command to record the output to a `screenlog.0` file when I press the shortcut keys the message is `Logfile "screenlog.O" closed.` But if I try to find it with `locate screenlog.0` it doesn't show up.

Where can I find the screenlog.0 file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the `screenlog.0` file in `screen`'s current working directory (cwd). This is either the directory that was the cwd when you started `screen`, or it's a directory you subsequently changed to using the `:chdir` `screen` command.

The easiest way to find out what this directory is is to open a new window with a shell in it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> and check the pwd of the new shell (which is usually visible straight away in the prompt).